# does speakers exhibit change of behavior when switching from one language to another?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, language, behavior

I have a strong belief that being a bilingual or multilingual when we switch from one language to another our behavior change accordingly. For example, my native language is Urdu, I feel comfortable, relax and calm when i am talking to someone in Urdu but when i am talking to someone in English i feel different. I am not comfortable. I'm continuously in my mind checking my grammar, sentence structure and stuff etc. I'm sure such things happen to others as well. Has any research that has been done on this topic?